# MFC Dialog disappearing while accessing application on Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog, tabcontrol, remote-desktop

I am using MFC dialog of style 'Popup', it also contains Tab Control. But dialog is disappearing while accessing the application on Remote Desktop Connection. Actually it is there, when I hover on it accidentally I see a tab but when I move my cursor somewhere else, it gets disappeared again. I have tried changing Dialog properties, but nothing is helping. Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use : `invalidate();`

That should work.